# Searching through a lot of links

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are bunch of hyperlinks on a page each under the  tag.

```
<h2 class="lk">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something">Something - Wikipedia</a>
</h2>

<h2 class="lk">
<a href="https://genius.com/The-beatles-something-lyrics">The Beatles – Something Lyrics | Genius Lyrics</a>
</h2>
```

.. and so on

I want to search if any of the hyperlink contains vimeo.com. If Yes, click on it, else click on a pagination link at the bottom **which is the next to** `<td class="cur">`. In this case, "Pg 2".

```
<td class="cur"><a aria-label="Pg 1" class="pg" href=""></a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Pg 2" class="pg" href=""></a></td>
```

Then again on Page 2, search for a bunch of hyperlinks each under the  tag.

If the hyperlink contains vimeo.com click on it, else click on a link **which is the next to** `<td class="cur">`. In this case, "Pg 3".

```
<td><a aria-label="Pg 1" class="pg" href=""></a></td>
<td class="cur"><a aria-label="Pg 2" class="pg" href=""></a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Pg 3" class="pg" href=""></a></td>
```

and so on.

How do I implement this in JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ["attribute contains" (`*=`) selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings):

```
$('a[href*="vimeo.com"]').click();
```

***but***, don't expect the browser to allow you to open a bunch of new tabs that way, at least not without checking with the user first.

Re the `aria-label="Pg 2"` link, there's no getting around an `if`:

```
var links = $('a[href*="vimeo.com"]');
if (links.length) {
    links = $('a[aria-label="Pg 2"]'); // If you only want one, use `.first()` on the end
}
links.click();
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I check if the part where if the url is not present, then click on aria-label="Pg 2" and so on. I do not want to write multiple if else statements. Any other way?

Comment: @CuriousDev - Sorry, missed that. I've updated the answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks again. The pages are numbered "Pg 2", "Pg 3" and so on. Let us say vimeo is on Pg "n" where n could be 7, 10 or 12. My question is how do I rewrite this code to go from Pg 1 to "n" searching for the text, till I find it.

Comment: @CuriousDev - In what context? If you click a link, the page gets torn down and your code isn't running anymore. It would help if you provided full details in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I added class="cur" and updated the question. I hope it is better now. Sorry if it isn't and I will try to rephrase it again.

Answer (score 0):

On this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/EduardoFerreiraJunior/pen/ReNVXL?editors=1010) i created an example of that working, just an example, probrably you'll need to make some changes to fit your scenario.

I didn't use `*=` like in T.J. Crowder but it also works with filter and regex.

Here's the javascript;

```
var search = function(current_page) {

var $links = getVimeoLinks();
//Click each link
$links.forEach(function(link){
    //Add _blank target, to avoid stoping execution after clicking
    $(link).attr('target', '_blank');
    link.click();
});

var next_page = (current_page+1);
//Click next page
//considering that next page button always have aria-label="Pg X"
//and that it's the only link with that pattern on aria-label
var next_page_link = $("a[aria-label^='Pg "+next_page+"']");

if(next_page_link.length === 0){
   alert('no more pages found after page'+current_page+' :(');
   return;
} else {
   next_page_link.click();
}

 return search(next_page);
}

//Add event to start searching
$('#search').on('click', function() {search(1)})


//function to get the vimeo links
var getVimeoLinks = function(){

var links = $('a').toArray().filter(function(link){
  $link = $(link);
  href = $link.attr('href');

  if(typeof href !== 'string')
      return false;

  return href.match(/vimeo\.com/) !== null;
});    

return links;
}
```

Comment: Great. Let me try this out . Thanks.